# java.io.FileNotFoundException (Access is denied) - file.canWrite() does not working

Tags: java, permissions, filenotfoundexception

I'm trying to empty a jasper file. Before write, I checked it for write access and I t gives me that I can write on it. But it terminates with `java.io.FileNotFoundException (Access is denied) - file.canWrite()`
What am I missing?

```
        try {
                File f = new File("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\XXXXXX\\XXX\\X\\X.jrxml");
                if(f.canWrite()){
                    BufferedWriter bf = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(f));
                    bf.write("");
                    bf.close();
                }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Do you have permission to write to that directory?

Comment: yes i have permissions.

Comment: Have you cross checked if some other process is still using that file? That can be a possible cause.

Comment: And also, are you running on Windows 7?

Answer (score 1):

Writing in your Program Files folder often has quite restricted access, and you must be on an Administrator account to do so usually. I would suggest you try saving your `.jrxml` in a more accessible directory outside `\\Program Files (x86)` like your `ApplicationData` folder, it may even already be there.
 You can also try something like Isolated Storage to ensure you have permissions,  [this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/IsolatedStorage.aspx)  should show you how to use it.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, canWrite may return true even if you cannot write on windows (according to this : http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=8060110). The javadoc is not really clear about that.

You can try using Files.isWritable if you are using at least java 7 to see if you have the expected result. Otherwise, it seems that the only way to check the rights is to try writing and see what happens.